# How can I stop Console.WriteLine repeating in while loop in if statement?

Tags: c#, if-statement, while-loop

```cs
using System;
namespace project
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) 
        {
            Console.Write("please enter a  name");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();


            while (true)
            {
                if (name.Length <= 4)
                {
                    //it gets stuck when I try a shorter name
                    Console.WriteLine("enter a longer name");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                else if (name.Length >= 20) 
                {
                    //it gets stuck when I try a shorter name
                    Console.WriteLine("enter a shorter  name");
                    Console.ReadLine();


                }
                else 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("welcome " +  name);
                }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have this problem in my program in which it can't stop repeating `Console.WriteLine("please enter a longer name");` when I try to test `Console.WriteLine( "please enter a shorter name");` the terminal still repeated "please enter a longer name"

Comment: You don't ever read a new input from the user into `name`, so `name` will always be the initial value.

Comment: "Don't stop ... repeeeeeating ..." :D ^^ You also don't `break` the loop. Or introduce a loop-condition variable / expression.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the new user input to the `name` variable. Like this:

```cs
using System;
namespace project
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) 
        {
            Console.Write("please enter a  name");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();

            while (true)
            {
                if (name.Length <= 4)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("enter a longer name");
                    name = Console.ReadLine();
                }
                else if (name.Length >= 20) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("enter a shorter  name");
                    name = Console.ReadLine();
                }
                else 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("welcome " +  name);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are still stuck in the while loop here.

Comment: Still not _exiting_ the loop, though.

Comment: you need to use `break`! Or restructure the whole code.

Answer (score 1):

Not particularly clean, but on the way:

```
using System;
namespace project
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) 
        {
            Console.Write("please enter a  name");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();

            // For your "main" flow it's enough to know 
            // the name is compliant to specs or not.
            // While it's not: get a new one.
            while (!ValidateName(name))
            {
                name = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"Welcome {name}");
        }

        // Check specs and return a "ok/fail"
        // Prompting the user could be factored out, 
        // but let's not get ahead of ourselves..
        private static bool ValidateName(string name)
        {
            if (name.Length <= 4)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("enter a longer name");
                return false;
            }
            if (name.Length >= 20) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("enter a shorter  name");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Don't try to do everything. Factor out separate concerns.

---

The problem in *your* code boiled down:

```
while(true)
{
    if( condition )
    {
        // intent: want to repeat
    }
    else
    {
       // intent: no need to repeat
    }
}
```

You see above: there is no indication in the code, when to stop looping.

To fix this you can either use `break`:

```
while(true)
{
    if( condition )
    {
        // intent: want to repeat
    }
    else
    {
       // intent: no need to repeat
       break;
    }
}
```

A variation with `continue` (which looks awkward at least to *me*):

```
while(true)
{
    if( condition )
    {
        // intent: want to repeat
        continue;
    }
    
    // this part is not executed if 'condition' resolves to 'true'
    // intent: no need to repeat
    break;
}
```

but it's probably better readable to actually use a loop condition

```
while(IsCondition()) // condition assessment factored out!
{
    // intent: want to repeat
}
// intent: no need to repeat
```

---

For reference see:

[Jump statements - `break`, `continue`, `return`, ...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/jump-statements)

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of `name` before your while loop? If it is less than 4 characters, the program will enter the while loop with that value for `name` and keep repeating "enter a longer name". Consider defining `name` outside of the while loop, and then setting its value with `name = Console.ReadLine()` inside of the loop.

This will pause the program execution until a new name is provided during each run through of the loop, but the loop will still be infinite, so you likley need an exit condition for the loop inside of your if statement which prints "welcome `name`".